# WordPress: PHP Variable showing null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am stuck in strange situation I am trying to pass PHP variable in JS by WordPress wp_localize_script and try to show it in console.log but it is outputting null. here is my code in functions.php

```
$conv = 1.36;
echo $conv;

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','cassets');
function cassets(){
  wp_enqueue_script("all-script",get_template_directory_uri().'/all-script.js',array('jquery'),'',true);
  $rate= array(
    'conv' => $conv,
  );
  wp_localize_script( 'all-script', 'rate', $rate);

}
```

and in all-script.js

```
var conv = rate.conv;
console.log(conv);
```

In console window it shows null but php echo value shows right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try wrapping your javascript in `$(document).ready(function () { // your script here })`

Comment: @tom-m I tried but didn't work.

Comment: @Teemu - This isn't a duplicate of that question. WordPress allows you to easily pass PHP variables to JavaScript with the `wp_localize_script()` function. His variables are just used out of scope.

Comment: @Xhynk Yeah, I realized it almost immediately after closing, reopened now.

Comment: `$conv` is not defined in your function.

Comment: @Teemu So how can I use $conv value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using your `$conv` variable out of scope. Take a look at [PHP's Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) documentation. You're defining `$conv` in the global scope, but referencing a local scope `$conv` in your `cassets()` function.

You need to use the function scoped `$conv`, either by defining it inside, or passing it to the function as a global variable or pass it as a [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Here's a few examples:

## Defining within the scope:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','cassets');
function cassets(){
    $conv = 1.36;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'all-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/all-script.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    $rate = array(
        'conv' => $conv,
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'all-script', 'rate', $rate );
}
```

## Passing it to the function as a global variable:

```
$conv = 1.36;

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cassets' );
function cassets(){
    global $conv;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'all-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/all-script.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    $rate = array(
        'conv' => $conv,
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'all-script', 'rate', $rate );
}
```

## Passing it via [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php):

```
$conv = 1.36;

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() use($conv){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'all-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/all-script.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    $rate = array(
        'conv' => $conv,
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'all-script', 'rate', $rate );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that you defined `$conv` outside your function.

Inside your function `$conv` was is undefined. (I think u should get a warning from php too).

Try this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','cassets');
function cassets(){
  $conv = 1.36;
  wp_enqueue_script("all-script",get_template_directory_uri().'/all-script.js',array('jquery'),'',true);
  $rate= array(
    'conv' => $conv,
  );
  wp_localize_script( 'all-script', 'rate', $rate);

}
```